# Google Analytics not showing correct session data

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, analytics

I have recently hired an SEO company to help me optimise my website in hoping of ranking higher in google, and getting better quality users (who are more likely to buy my product)

After giving the SEO company admin privileges in my google-analytics, I am convinced they have changed/broken something so that my session data is no longer showing anything other than 0 (despite my ad-words receiving clicks to my site and my own daily views)

Where are potential places in analytics that I can start looking to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Is the JavaScript snippet for Google Analytics still installed on the site?   If you use real time reporting in Google Analytics, do you see data coming in as you browse the site?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an unfiltered view or test view in your Google Analytics account? If you do, start looking in that view to see if you are collecting data there. If daa is visible there it could be a filter in your main view blocking your sessions.
If you don't have an unfiltered view, add one right away with no filters or anything. Just let raw data flow into that view. The check that view after 24h to see if you can notice any difference. If the result is the same, you can most likely rule out filter issues.
Check your tracking code. Do you still have tracking code on all your pages? Does it have the correct GA ID? Look like this: UA-12345678-9

If you are using Google Chrome browser you can install the extension called Google Tag Assistant. Use it to verify that your tracking code is working and what ID it sends your data to.